# Variables inside of strings return 1

Tags: php, heredoc

I was making a test page in which I have a form with the post method and a destination page. The main goal was to output the submitted values to a file called `UserInfo.txt`.

That worked, but when I looked into the file, all the variables I had put inside the string that was outputted into the file, were `1`s.

My code is:

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$emailb = $_POST['emailb'];

$UserInfo = <<<EOT
[NAME] = $fname, $lname
[AGE] = $age
[EMAIL] = $email
EOT;
file_put_contents("UserInfo.txt", $UserInfo, FILE_APPEND);
```

The file output was:

```
[NAME] = 1, 1
[AGE] = 1
[EMAIL] = 1
```

HTML form:

```
<form action="7_dest.php" method="POST">
    <p>First name:<input type="text" name="fname" step=0> </p>
    <p>Last name:<input type="text" name="lname" step=0> </p>
    <p>Age:<input type="number" name="age"> </p>
    <p>E-mail:<input type="email" name="email" step=0> </p>
    <p>Confirm E-mail:<input type="email" name="emailb" step=0> </p>
    <p><input type="submit"> </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML form?

Comment: The HTML form of the form?

Comment: Yes, the HTML `<form>`, so we can see the input names and types and such.

Comment: `print_f($_POST);` will shed some light on the culprit. As others already suggested in their comments, you probably have a bad-coded form.

Comment: This might be a long shot, but there is a chance your `step` attribute causes the browser to interpret the field as a type `number`.

Comment: 'print_r($_POST);' returned this: 'Array ( [fname] => John [lname] => Notreal [age] => 24 [email] => example@gmail.com [emailb] => example@gmail.com )'

Comment: @GerardvanHelden I tried removing the step attribute but it did not affect the output.

Comment: What happens if you `print_r($UserInfo);` ?

Comment: @DanLowe It outputs the string with '1's again...

Comment: Did you try adding `{}` around the variables so it would look something like `[NAME] = {$fname}, {$lname}`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the culprit after some research and plain testing.
Between the variable assigning bit and the heredoc syntax there was an `if` statement.
Since `if` statements use the **local variable scope** and the values were assigned in the **global variable scope** the variables were NOT assigned inside of the `if` statement.
As a  result, the variables were not assigned and could thereby not be used.
I fixed it by copying the assigning bit and pasting it inside the `if statement`.

Here is what the code looks like now:

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$emailb = $_POST['emailb'];
if (){ //I had a lot of tests here, removed them for the sake of a nice page
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $emailb = $_POST['emailb'];
$UserInfo = <<<EOT
[NAME] = $fname, $lname
[AGE] = $age
[EMAIL] = $email
EOT;
file_put_contents("UserInfo.txt", $UserInfo, FILE_APPEND);
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong";
} ?>
```